# Probability of Second ball when two balls are picked from a bin in a set of bins without replacement

Tags: probability

There are $n$ bins of which the $i$th contains $(i-1)$ green balls and $(n-i)$ black balls. You pick a bin at random and remove two balls at random without replacement. What is the probability that the second ball is black?

Comment: Can you show how you attempted to solve the problem?

Comment: So each bin has $(n-1)$ balls ?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Take pairs of bins $(1,n), (2,n-1)... $ and so on,  and see what the symmetry suggests.

Comment: Symmetry says every one of the $n(n-1)$ balls has equal prior probability to be the second ball removed from a bin. So it's a simple counting exercise (further exploiting the symmetry observed by true blue anil).

Answer (score 1):

There are $n(n-1)$ total balls. Half are green and half are black. Since you are drawing from the total pool and ignoring the first pick, the probability is the same as drawing one ball from the total pool. $P=0.5$

Proof: \begin{align}P&=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{1+2+3+\cdots+(n-1)}{n-1}\\&=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{n-1}\\&=\frac{n(n-1)}{2n(n-1)}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

To me, this problem entails an interesting aspect that is worth to spell out.
Assume to have a bin with *g* green balls and *b* black balls, let's indicate it as [g, b]. 
When we extract one ball from it, we get the following scheme:
$$ \begin{gathered}
  \text{prob}\text{. }\frac{g}
{{g + b}}\quad  \to \quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \text{to select }1\text{ green ball}\text{,} \hfill \\
  \text{leaving a }\left[ {g - 1,\;b} \right]\text{ bin} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\
  \text{prob}\text{. }\frac{b}
{{g + b}}\quad  \to \quad \left\{ \begin{gathered}
  \text{to select }1\text{ black ball}\text{,} \hfill \\
  \text{leaving a }\left[ {g,\;b - 1} \right]\text{ bin} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} $$

Therefore the ball we extracted has an average hue of $\frac{g} {b}$ and the remaining bin, on the average, will have a composition of
$$\left[ {\frac{{g\left( {g - 1} \right) + bg}}
{{g + b}},\frac{{bg + b\left( {b - 1} \right)}}
{{g + b}}} \right] = \left[ {g\frac{{g + b - 1}}
{{g + b}},b\frac{{g + b - 1}}
{{g + b}}} \right]$$
i.e. with an unchanged ratio of  $\frac{g} {b}$.
The same happens when extracting further balls, till the bin gets empty,
and the same is true if the starting bin contains balls of multiple colors.

That makes clear why, In the case proposed, the answer is  1/2.

Answer (score 0):

Tried it with a sample of 5 bins.. So the distribution of balls (green, black) would be (0,4), (1,3),(2,2),(3,1) and (4,0)...

Prob of getting black as second ball from bin 1 P(1)-1, 
P(2)-1*3/3 or n-2/n-2
P(3)-1*2/3 or n-3/n-2
..
..
P(n)-0

Then adding these should give us the result, Correct?

Comment: Probability of getting black as second ball from bin $i$ is $\frac{n-i}{n-1}$

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am little confused. Please see if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Since first ball can be anything, it is simply probability of drawing any ball from the sample set, which is a sure event, correct? this means it is always 1.   So the second will be the probability of choosing red as second ball - n-i/n-1 for n bins, correct? so the answer should be n(n-i)/(n-1) only, correct? How did we arrive at 1/2?

Comment: I mean, got the part, n(n-1)/2(n-1)... which then becomes n/2... My question is more specific about the initial 1/n...

Comment: The $1/n$ comes from choosing a bin. For each bin,  probability is $\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-i}{n-1}$ The sum for all bins is $\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2(n-1)}$

Comment: Let us split this and make it for one bin... Probability of choosing second ball as red will be n-i/n-1... Now we need to repeat this for n bins... Which is nothing but 1/n-1 * [1+2+3+...+n-1 as the nth bin is going to have no red balls], correct? This then translates to 1/n-1*n(n-1)/2 ==> n/2

Comment: Prob of choosing second ball as red = prob of choosing any ball as first * probability of choosing red ball as second.  Since, the prob of choosing any ball is sure event, it will be one.  So, prob of choosing second ball as red will be (n-i)/(n-1), correct? So where is that 1/n coming from?